# Add Icon to QTabWidget Bar

Tags: qt, qt5

My question is that I want to set an icon to QTabWidget at right side. I want this for QTabWidget Bar not for individual tabs.
How should i add this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could show a picture of what you want to get. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add an icon to a QTabWidget (not for each tab)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43785389/how-to-add-an-icon-to-a-qtabwidget-not-for-each-tab)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add an icon to a QTabWidget (not for each tab)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43785389/how-to-add-an-icon-to-a-qtabwidget-not-for-each-tab)